# Create a matrix using values from a tuple with numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix with values based on `x,y` values I have stored in a tuple. I use a loop to iterate over the tuple and perform a simple calculation on the data:

```
import numpy as np

# Trying to fit quadratic equation to the measured dots

N = 6
num_of_params = 3

# x values
x = (1,4,3,5,2,6)

# y values
y = (3.96, 24.96,14.15,39.8,7.07,59.4)

# X is a matrix N * 3 with the x values to the power of {0,1,2}
X = np.zeros((N,3))
Y = np.zeros((N,1))

print X,"\n\n",Y

for i in range(len(x)):
    for p in range(num_of_params):
        X[i][p] = x[i]**(num_of_params - p - 1)
    Y[i] = y[i]

print "\n\n"
print X,"\n\n",Y
```

Is this can be achieved in an easier way? I'm looking for some way to init the matrix like `X = np.zeros((N,3), read_values_from = x)`

Is it possible? Is there another simple way?

*Python 2.7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend array version of `x` to `2D` with a singleton dim (dim with length=1) along the second one using `np.newaxis/None`. This lets us leverage [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get the `2D` output in a vectorized manner. Similar philosophy for `y`.

Hence, the implementation would be -

```
X = np.asarray(x)[:,None]**(num_of_params - np.arange(num_of_params)  - 1)
Y = np.asarray(y)[:,None]
```

Or use the built-in outer method for `np.power` to get `X` that takes care of the array conversion under the hoods -

```
X = np.power.outer(x, num_of_params - np.arange(num_of_params)  - 1)
```

Alternatively, for `Y`, use `np.expand_dims` -

```
Y = np.expand_dims(y,1)
```